# Pandas concat multiple sheets appending new column for each sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel Workbook with 36 sheets within.  Each sheet has the same columns - there are only 5 columns that I actually need (below) but there are a bunch more.  Each sheet is follows this naming convention YYYY-MM-DD MRR

| Subscription ID | Activated At | Activated For (days) | Current Status | MRR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

What I am trying to do is create a new excel sheet that has
`["Subscription ID", "Activated At", "Activated For (days)", "Current Status", "Pasue Start Date", "Pause End Date", "Pause End Status"]`
then there will be 36 columns for the MRR of each month for the last 3 years.

This is my first time working with Pandas so I am running into some issues as to how to do this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. (note that I am still having trouble just concatenating the sheets together with only the columns I need)

The Subscription ID is going to be the Unique Key.  An example row of the final output will look like this.

This is an example of one row that is paused - I am going to calculate the pause date (Activated At date plus Activated For num of days) then enter it into the cell.
The second row is an active subscription

| Subscription ID | Activated At | Activated For (days) | Current Status | Pause Start Date | Pause End Date | Pause End Status | Jan 2019 MRR | ... | Jan 2022 MRR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2019-01-01 | 899 | Paused | 2021-07-08 | NaN | Paused | $75 | ... | $10 |
| 0002 | 2019-01-02 | 999 | Active | NaN | NaN | NaN | $75 | ... | $75 |

```
import pandas as pd

excel = 'Total_MRR_ALL.xlsx'

sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name=None, usecols="B,E,F,G,H")
column_names = ["Subscription ID", "Activated At", "Activated For (days)", "Current Status", "Pasue Start Date", "Pause End Date", "Pause End Status"]
master = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names).set_index("Subscription ID")

for sheetname, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
    master[sheetname] = ""

    x = 0
    if(sheetname != "Master"):
        for row in sheet.itertuples(index=False):
            
            
            if( x<1 ):
                new_row_dictionary = {
                    "Subscription ID" : row[0],
                    "Activated At": row[1],
                    "Activated For (days)": row[2],
                    "Current Status" : row[3],
                    "Pasue Start Date": "",
                    "Pause End Date": "",
                    "Pause End Status": "",
                    sheetname: row[4]
                }
                
                print(row[0], " ",row[1], " ", row[2], " ", row[3], " " , row[4] )
                
                master.loc[len(master)-1] = new_row_dictionary 
            x+=1
        
master.to_csv("output.csv")

# B                 E               F                   G               H
# Subscription ID   Activated At    Active For (days)   Current Status  MRR

# master.to_csv("output.csv")
#   B                   E               F                   G                   #                   #               #                   H - H+36
#   Subscription ID     Activated At    Active For (days)   Current Status      Pause Start Date    Pause End Date  Pause End Status    Mothly MRR
```

**Update**
With some help from Pankaj here is my updated code (much easier).

```
import pandas as pd

excel = 'Total_MRR_ALL_v2.xlsx'

df = (pd.concat(pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name=None, usecols="B,E,F,G,H", index_col=2), axis=0 ).reset_index(level=1, drop=False).rename_axis('Month').reset_index())

df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

The issue I am facing now is that all of the Sheet names are in a single column as such:
[image: Excel Sheets as single column]

What I need is for the Month column to convert each unique month into its own column where the Subscription ID is the unique identifier and then the months are populated with the MRR for each respective month:
[image: Monthly MRR displayed as individual columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need the for loop at all. Excel sheet data can be combined easily using concat function. Additional columns can be added by just initialising them. Then you can use logic to populate values for those additional columns.

Consider this code:

```
import pandas as pd

excel = 'Total_MRR_ALL.xlsx'

sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name=None, usecols="A,B,C,D,E,F,G")
column_names = ["Subscription ID", "Activated At", "Activated For (days)", "Current Status", "Pause Start Date", "Pause End Date", "Pause End Status"]

# combine all sheets to a single dataframe
master = pd.concat(sheets_dict.values())
master = master.set_index("Subscription ID")

# new columns added with initial values. Populate calculated values
master['Jan 2019 MRR'] = 0;
master['Feb 2019 MRR'] = 'a';
master['Mar 2019 MRR'] = '';
        
# prints the output to csv
master.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: This was very helpful! I used your code plus some other things I found to get a close enough base for what I am trying to accomplish. I just updated my original post to add some more insight - basically I am now given a single row with all of the Subscription ID + Month + MRR combos.  Do you know how I convert the Month column to rows then populate the MRR into each row effectively removing duplicate lines.

Comment: What you need is a groupby. For example `df.groupby(['Subscription ID', 'Activated At', 'Active For (days)', 'Current Status']).sum()`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it